# Select 2 records with more current months C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to make a query to "paymentEvolutionDetail.EvolutionPaymentSystemsByMonth" where a new data is created that stores those 2 most current records that have the same "paymentSystemId".

This is how my look "paymentEvolutionDetail.EvolutionPaymentSystemsByMonth":

```
var evolutionPaymentSystemsByMonth = new[]
{
    (paymentSystemId: 8, paymentSystem: "PAGO FACIL", transactions: 5, month: 12, year: 2021),
    (paymentSystemId: 4, paymentSystem: "PAGOMISCUENTAS", transactions: 3, month: 12, year: 2021),
    (paymentSystemId: 5, paymentSystem: "RED LINK", transactions: 2, month: 12, year: 2021),
    (paymentSystemId: 4, paymentSystem: "PAGOMISCUENTAS", transactions: 4, month: 1, year: 2022),
    (paymentSystemId: 5, paymentSystem: "RED LINK", transactions: 2, month: 1, year: 2022),
    (paymentSystemId: 8, paymentSystem: "PAGO FACIL", transactions: 3, month: 1, year: 2022),
    (paymentSystemId: 4, paymentSystem: "PAGOMISCUENTAS", transactions: 2, month: 2, year: 2022),
    (paymentSystemId: 5, paymentSystem: "RED LINK", transactions: 1, month: 2, year: 2022),
    (paymentSystemId: 8, paymentSystem: "PAGO FACIL", transactions: 3, month: 2, year: 2022),
};
```

I need to create a new data where the 2 records are saved with the most current month and year and that have the same paymentSystemId. So, this array would go from length 9 to 6.

I tried to do it with two foreachs but it's so many loops that I got lost. I hope you can help me! From already thank you very much.

This is the example of the array taken from the Google console but when I tried to use the foreachs, I converted the array with ToList()

Comment: Instead of Array, use typed list where you can use lambda expression

Comment: @Chandana Yes, I need to clarify that. When trying to use the two foreachs, pass the array with ToList().

Comment: can we see the c# that generates this, is it a database or what? What type of objects do you have

Comment: @Chandana That can work for me! If I get the solution, I'll post it. Thanks!

Comment: The month being a string makes this harder work than it needs to be; can you make month numeric instead?

Comment: Where possible please post data as valid C# code.

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, I already modified both the month and the year and converted it to int to make it easier.

Comment: @GianfrancoGrigera Your post hasn't been edited for 14 hours and it still shows months and days being stored as strings. Also, using 2-digit years is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to create a new data where the 2 records are saved with the most current month and year and that have the same paymentSystemId. So, this array would go from length 9 to 6.

With LINQ, it would perhaps look like:

```
var recent2 = evolutionPaymentSystemsByMonth
  .GroupBy(e => e.paymentSystemId, (k,g) => g.OrderByDescending(e => e.year).ThenByDescending(e => e.month).Take(2))
  .SelectMany(g => g)
  .ToArray();
```

On the assumption that the data is like ...:

```
var evolutionPaymentSystemsByMonth = new[]
{
    (paymentSystemId: 8, transactions: 5, month: 12, year: 21, paymentSystem: "PAGO FACIL"),
    (paymentSystemId: 4, transactions: 3, month: 12, year: 21, paymentSystem: "PAGOMISCUENTAS"),
    (paymentSystemId: 5, transactions: 2, month: 12, year: 21, paymentSystem: "RED LINK"),
    (paymentSystemId: 4, transactions: 4, month: 1,  year: 22, paymentSystem: "PAGOMISCUENTAS"),
    (paymentSystemId: 5, transactions: 2, month: 1,  year: 22, paymentSystem: "RED LINK"),
    (paymentSystemId: 8, transactions: 3, month: 1,  year: 22, paymentSystem: "PAGO FACIL"),
    (paymentSystemId: 4, transactions: 2, month: 2,  year: 22, paymentSystem: "PAGOMISCUENTAS"),
    (paymentSystemId: 5, transactions: 1, month: 2,  year: 22, paymentSystem: "RED LINK"),
    (paymentSystemId: 8, transactions: 3, month: 2,  year: 22, paymentSystem: "PAGO FACIL"),
};
```

<sup>Note: it's reorganized to be neater but this has no overall effect on the tuple in this case. Note though that reordering a tuple can affect how it sorts</sup>

Footnote: doing that reorg just reminded me something; your LINQ can be made simpler if you reorganize the tuple so what you sort by comes first:

```
var evolutionPaymentSystemsByMonth = new[]
{
    (year: 21, month: 12, paymentSystemId: 8, transactions: 5, paymentSystem: "PAGO FACIL"),
    (year: 21, month: 12, paymentSystemId: 4, transactions: 3, paymentSystem: "PAGOMISCUENTAS"),
    (year: 21, month: 12, paymentSystemId: 5, transactions: 2, paymentSystem: "RED LINK"),
    (year: 22, month: 1,  paymentSystemId: 4, transactions: 4, paymentSystem: "PAGOMISCUENTAS"),
    (year: 22, month: 1,  paymentSystemId: 5, transactions: 2, paymentSystem: "RED LINK"),
    (year: 22, month: 1,  paymentSystemId: 8, transactions: 3, paymentSystem: "PAGO FACIL"),
    (year: 22, month: 2,  paymentSystemId: 4, transactions: 2, paymentSystem: "PAGOMISCUENTAS"),
    (year: 22, month: 2,  paymentSystemId: 5, transactions: 1, paymentSystem: "RED LINK"),
    (year: 22, month: 2,  paymentSystemId: 8, transactions: 3, paymentSystem: "PAGO FACIL"),
};
```

Now you can just order the tuple by itself descending; because tuples sort in order of their items from left to right, it saves us some to put the year and month first, then we can just OrderByDescending the tuple itself

```
        var recent2 = evolutionPaymentSystemsByMonth
          .GroupBy(e => e.paymentSystemId, (k, g) => g.OrderByDescending(e=>e).Take(2))
          .SelectMany(g => g)
          .ToArray();
```

Comment: I'll give you an upvote if you align `evolutionPaymentSystemsByMonth`'s value-tuples' members' data into vertical columns by comma position. (Sorry, but unaligned code is a _eyebrow-twitch_ peeve of mine...)

Comment: Yep, bugs me too../

Comment: _psssst_: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cpmcgrath.Codealignment

Comment: Now I just need Visual Studio for iPhone! :D

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you very much for the help! Finally, I managed to do it in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to do it as follows:

```
 paymentEvolutionDetail.EvolutionPaymentSystemsByMonth.GroupBy(x => x.PaymentSystemId)
     .SelectMany(x => x.OrderByDescending(g => g.Year)
     .ThenByDescending(g => g.Month)
     .Take(2)).ToList();
```